# Running asp.net 4.5 app visual studio 2017 "your internet access is blocked"

Tags: c#

I've created an asp.net 4.5 application in Visual studio 2017 however when I run it I get an message in chrome saying `your internet access is blocked`. I'm sure why this is happening and I'm struggling to find any resources online that fixes this issue.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running visual studio as administrator (right click, run as administrator)

Comment: @FJT I have added a screenshot

Comment: you really need to run in https?

Comment: @mjwills running as admin doesn't seem to fix the issue

Comment: @DeyvisonSouto yes I need to as a results of a CSP filter policy

Comment: Your IIS is properly configured for that. Enabled the https binding and using a trusted certificated for localhost

Comment: @DeyvisonSouto how would I do this

Comment: Try Settings, scroll down to advanced and expand.  Go to systems, then open proxy settings. Click on Lan Settings, and check whether you are using a proxy server - if you are, then click 'Bypass proxy for local addresses'.

Comment: @FJT I have tried that but it still gives the same error should i put an address or a port as well?

Comment: What do you get if you run diagnostics?

Comment: @FJT Do you mean azure diagnostics? if so the live one is fine and diagnostics say its healthy i can run it and debug it on the live site the only issue is only with localhost

Comment: I meant clicking the 'run windows network diagnostics' on the error message.

Comment: Ah yes done that before posting it says no issues where detected.

Comment: @mjwills yes I am I've no problem accessing the internet it's just seems to be my local host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to run an SSL secured page on IIS Express using the non-secure IIS option.
To Fix this run your project and look at the taskbar system tray for the IIS express icon [image]

Right click on that and you will see two options one with an http and one with https click on the https on and this should open the website properly
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you in your home local network or in your company network? If in company your firewall can block website on the port or badly defined proxy.

Comment: I am in a company network but i have contacted our IT and asked them to disable the firewall on my pc momentarily so i can try it out but still gives me the same error

Comment: Have you got the same problem for both Lan and WLan connection? I had the same problem in my company and the problem was that I had set different proxy for Lan and wLan connection.